# Difference between Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition and Type.ContainsGenericParameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

The `System.Type` type contains the properties [IsGenericTypeDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictypedefinition.aspx) and [ContainsGenericParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.containsgenericparameters.aspx). After reading the MSDN documentation I conclude that both properties exist to to check whether a type is an open or closed generic type.

However, I fail to see what the difference is between the two, and when you want to use one over the other.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Type.ContainsGenericParameters` is *recursive*:

```
var genericList = typeof(List<>);
var listOfSomeUnknownTypeOfList = genericList.MakeGenericType(genericList);
listOfSomeUnknownTypeOfList.IsGenericTypeDefinition;  // => false
listOfSomeUnknownTypeOfList.ContainsGenericParameters; // => true
```

What happens here is that `listOfSomeUnknownTypeOfList` is not a generic type definition itself because its type parameter is known to be a `List<T>` for some T. However, since the type of `listOfSomeUnknownTypeOfList` is not exactly known (because its type argument is a type definition) `ContainsGenericParameters` is `true`.

Answer (score 5):

`ContainsGenericParameters` is a recursive version of `IsGenericTypeDefinition`.

`typeof(List<Func<>>).IsGenericTypeDefinition` is false.

Comment: You can't actually do typeof(List<Func<>>).. C# complains about an "Unexpected use of an unbound generic name.".

Answer (score 4):

There is a table under [`IsGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype.aspx) that tries to highlight some differences:

> The `IsGenericTypeDefinition` property is true.
>
> Defines a generic type. A constructed type is created by calling the `MakeGenericType` method on a `Type` object that represents a generic type definition and specifying an array of type arguments.

or:

> The `ContainsGenericParameters` property is true.
>
> Examples are a generic type that has unassigned type parameters, a type that is nested in a generic type definition or in an open constructed type, or a generic type that has a type argument for which the `ContainsGenericParameters` property is true.

So they're not precisely the same.