# Why is the BaseType of a Generic Type Definition not itself a Generic Type Definition when possible?

Tags: c#, .net, types, type-systems, .net-4.6

In the example below, I'm trying to understand why the `BaseType` is not a generic type definition and more generally, why it isn't just equal to the `typeof(List<>)`

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
}

// this is true by definition
typeof(List<>).IsGenericTypeDefinition

// this is false
// also the BaseType.FullName is null ?!?
// also BaseType.IsConstructedGenericType is true ?!?!?
// as such, BaseType != typeof(List<>)
typeof(MyList<>).BaseType.IsGenericTypeDefinition;
```

---

**EDIT - Here are some useful links on related topics**:

[Difference between Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition and Type.ContainsGenericParameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012733/difference-between-type-isgenerictypedefinition-and-type-containsgenericparamete)

[What exactly is an "open generic type" in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net)

[Generics -Open and closed constructed Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types)

[Detect if a generic type is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811514/detect-if-a-generic-type-is-open)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenerictype

[Difference between IsGenericType and IsGenericTypeDefinition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772922/difference-between-isgenerictype-and-isgenerictypedefinition)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net) can give you some ideas

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772922/difference-between-isgenerictype-and-isgenerictypedefinition) could also be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the links!  I'm including those in the original post for reference, along with some others I found.

Comment: Interestingly, the documentation for `Type.BaseType` covers all cases *except* for the case of a generic type definition, so if you want to get technical, the result isn't even properly defined. What is actually returned is an open type `List<T>`, with `T` unbound (i.e. `.GetGenericParameters()[0].IsGenericParameter == true`). This is not unreasonable, but it's still not documented.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I found the same; I read the documentation like 5 times to make sure I wasn't missing anything but it's not addressed!  I agree that it's not unreasonable, but it does seems sub-optimal and not as intuitive as returning the generic type definition.